# Angular cannot build in prod mode

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular website, the build works if i don't use the --prod, i have tried to set allowJs: false, the build passe, but the website doesn't work.
Here are the configuration files:

```
tsconfig.json

{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "node_modules/json-typescript-mapper/libs/utils.ts",
    "node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/level.ts",
    "node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/logger.ts",
    "node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/providers.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [],
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "node_modules",
    "definitions",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

The error is:

```
error TS5055: cannot write file D:/**/node_modules/core-js/modules/es7.reflect.get-own-metadata.js' because it would overwrite input file. Adding a tsconfig.json file will help organze projects that contain both Typescript and Javascript files. Learn more at https://aka.ms/tsconfig
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any errors during the build process? Do you get errors in the console when you are trying to run the `--prod` version? Try to change "lib": [ "es2017", to es2015

Comment: The error is: error TS5055: cannot write file D:/**/node_modules/core-js/modules/es7.reflect.get-own-metadata.js' because it would overwrite input file.  Adding a tsconfig.json file will help organze projects that contain both Typescript and Javascript files. Learn more at https://aka.ms/tsconfig

Comment: Firstly set allowJs to true. Then build in production mode. What is the error? If the same error happens, you need `tsconfig.json` file. Create that config file by executing `tsc --init`, then build again

Comment: In fact, i have already tsconfig.json in the on the first level, the first part of this post is the content of this file tsconfig.json, then in the src/ folder, i have tsconfig.app.json, i don't understand.

Comment: I used the angular cli to create the project, so these files are created automatically by the command, i have tried to set the es2017 to es2016, but the same error